# In REDIS Georadius command with STOREDIST option, do I have to manually delete the STOREDIST key?

Tags: redis, geo

The  GEORADIUS command takes the STORE / STOREDIST  option along with the name of a key to a sorted set. https://redis.io/commands/georadius

I have a web page where I am displaying a paginated list of geos locations by distance from a center. The STOREDIST is really useful for this scenario . However, I am concerned if I have to manually delete these storedist keys periodically ?

Comment: You can set `TTL` on these keys. When these keys are expired, they will be removed automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, looks like you have to remove those keys yourself. As far as I see there is no `expire` set on it: https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/4.0/src/geo.c#L659

As noted, you can set TTL on those keys.